# sndfile not found on your system and thus audioinfo is not functional (brew octave 4.0.0 mac)

Tags: octave, homebrew

After upgrading to Octave 4.0.0 from 3.8.2 using brew upgrade on a Mac OS X, I'm now getting this error when trying to use `wavread`:

> error: sndfile not found on your system and thus audioinfo is not functional
>   error: called from
>       wavread at line 91 column 8

I tried re-installing libsndfile, port audio, and even octave but still could not resolve this.

Comment: Have you tried what is suggested in [this thread](http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/I-cant-use-wavread-with-octave-4-0-under-ubuntu-td4671113.html) from the Octave mail list?

Comment: No, those seem to be Ubuntu specific

Comment: You've used this formula? https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/blob/master/octave.rb You can have a log in your config.log and search for sndfile to see why the sndfile support was disabled

Comment: I'll have to re-try again later. For now I've switched to casked version of octave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the homebrew formula for Octave doesn't list portaudio and libsndfile as dependencies. Homebrew appears to run a special version of pkg-config during installation, which only has access to libraries that are explicitly listed as dependencies in the formula.

I managed to get it to work by doing

```
brew edit octave
```

then adding these lines somewhere near the top of the formula:

```
depends_on "libsndfile"
depends_on "portaudio"
```

and these lines a bit lower down, where the args string to the `configure` command is being constructed

```
args << "--with-portaudio"
args << "--with-sndfile"
```

Then install octave and ensure that it builds from source. Something like

```
brew install octave --build-from-source --with-gui
```

Ideally portaudio and sndfile would be enabled with a switch like `--with-audio` or something. If I get a chance I'll submit a pull request to homebrew with the necessary changes.

#### Edit: 12th October 2015

This is now the subject of a pull request in the homebrew-science tap
https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/pull/2875